# Possible to host a django site on github pages?

Tags: django, github

I'm new to django, and have a small finished project I'd like to publish online. Is it possible to host my site as a github project page, or do I have to use a service like OpenShift?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can deploy Django on a physical server or VPS (see the [deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/)). You don't have to use a a platform as a service like OpenShift or Heroku.

It is not possible to host a Django site on Github pages. Github pages is for static sites, whereas Django requires Python to generate pages dynamically.

Comment: That's a bummer! Thank you for letting me know -- I will accept your answer shortly.

Comment: if I can't host my site on github pages directly, is it possible to have the url of my site (hosted on OpenShift or another service) be the url of a github project page?

Comment: I don't think Github allow that. Normally, people point their own domain e.g.  `myproject.com` at GitHub pages, they don't want to point `myproject.github.io` somewhere else.

Comment: This is completely dependent on how your site works, but if it's more or less a brochure, django-medusa will allow you to create and maintain a database driven site using Django, but also converted into a static site that can be hosted anywhere: https://github.com/alsoicode/django-medusa

Answer (score 14):

If you do not want to use OpenShift, but instead would prefer a more python-centric environment, I just discovered [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) today. They appear to allow you to [host Django websites](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/DjangoTutorial) and you can even [use it for the Django tutorial](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/FollowingTheDjangoTutorial).

Comment: Truly useful tip

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, that may depend on whether you can make a static site using django, because GitHub will work for you if you have a static site.