# index.html file for GitHub repository website

Tags: html, css, django, github, web-development-server

I am attempting to publish my website that I have uploaded into a github repository. When I run the website locally (using django) I can see it working perfectly with all of my backgrounds and animations from the css files. This was using the index.html file in the templates folder.

When I attempted to run using the github pages, I had to create an index.html file in the main folder so that it can be run from the start. However, this causes my website to include only text files and images, no animations, backgrounds, or colors from my css files.

The settings.py has STATIC_URL = '/static/'

How can I use the new index.html to call all of my css files?

1. Folder
   static (folder)
   css
   js
   scss
   img
   _init__.py
   settings.py
   urls.py
2. Other Folder
   migrations (folder)
   templates (folder)
   index.html
   views.py
   admin.py
   **init**.py
   index.py (new for github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked, GitHub Pages is only for static applications and won't be able to host a Django application. You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880626/possible-to-host-a-django-site-on-github-pages).