# Deploying a Django App to GitHub - Landing page isn't being displayed

Tags: python, django, github

I'm trying to deploy my Django application on github. Files have been uploaded successfully, the url works fine, but when I go the site https://qasim-khan1.github.io/blog/

It doesn't direct me to my landing page. It shows nothing, simply 'Blog' written in bold text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not host Django app on GitHub, GitHub doesn't support hosting of dynamic site.

Comment: I tried it before with a small app, it worked fine.

Comment: Once check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880626/possible-to-host-a-django-site-on-github-pages                     and can you post the link of that small app which you tried before